# Error converting data type varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have , in sql server ,  a parameter as :

```
@DoBEmp = '24/6/1990'
```

passed to sql , 
when I try to insert it into table , this error raises :

```
Error converting data type varchar to date.
```

how can i insert it properly

Comment: Why are you passing a string to a varchar parameter? Try passing a date to a datetime parameter, and not formatting your dates using ambiguous formats...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [setting the date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189491.aspx)?

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@DoBEmp = CONVERT(date,'24/6/1990',103)
```

dd/mm/yyyy is style 103

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure that CONVERT will correctly parse the date even if the `DATEFORMAT` wasn't explicitely set to `dmy`?

Comment: Yes.  The linked documentation page explains it. If you rely on SET DATEFORMAT, the result is nondeterministic and cannot be used to index views, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern `'10/6/1990'` can be ambiguate (it can mean - 10 of June or 6 of Oct).
Provide a format or use this pattern:

```
SET @DoBEmp = '1990-6-24'
```